# Why is my object destructed only once when serializing it from another app domain?

Tags: c#

Consider this:

```
[Serializable]
class B
{
    public B() { Console.WriteLine("Creating B in " + AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName); }
    ~B() { Console.WriteLine("Finalizing B in " + AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName); }
}

class C : MarshalByRefObject
{
    public C() { Console.WriteLine("Creating C in " + AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName); }
    ~C() { Console.WriteLine("Finalizing C in " + AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName); }
}


class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        AppDomain appDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("myAppDomain");
        B b = (B)appDomain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().FullName, typeof(B).FullName);
        C c = (C)appDomain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().FullName, typeof(C).FullName);
        AppDomain.Unload(appDomain);
        GC.Collect();
    }
}
```

The output I'm getting is:

```
Creating B in myAppDomain
Creating C in myAppDomain
Finalizing C in myAppDomain
Finalizing B in myAppDomain
```

However , I would expect that `B` would be finalized twice (once for each app domain) since it's being serialized. What am I missing?

Comment: Try to move the code before GC.Collect Inside another method (so the variable scope ends even in debug) then add a GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()

Comment: Or add `b = null;` before the GC.Collect - should have the same effect.

Comment: Or test in Release mode.